# How to pass styles from material icons ui v4 to v5 maintaining the same styles?

Tags: javascript

So i was currently following a tutorial where they were using material ui icons but with the version from a year ago, i had to made some changes as i followed the tutorial. But then the styles part came along and i don't know how to change the styles to they work in version five of material ui.
Here is the jsx code he uses:

```
import { AppBar, Toolbar, Typography, InputBase, Box} from '@material-ui/core'
import SearchIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Search'

import useStyles from './styles'

const Header = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <AppBar position='static'>
            <Toolbar className={classes.toolbar}>
                <Typography variant = 'h5' className={classes.title}>
                     Travel Advisor
                </Typography>
                <Box display = 'flex'>
                <Typography variant = 'h6' className={classes.title}>
                     Explore new places
                </Typography>
                {/*<Autocomplete>*/}
                    <div className={classes.search}>
                       <div className={classes.searchIcon}> 
                       <SearchIcon />
                       </div>
                       <InputBase placeholder="Search..." classes={{root: classes.inputRoot, input: classes.inputInput}}/>
                    </div>
                {/*<Autocomplete>*/}
                </Box>
            </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
    )
}

export default Header
```

Here is the styles.js code he uses:

```
import { alpha, makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

export default makeStyles((theme) =\> ({
title: {
display: 'none',
\[theme.breakpoints.up('sm')\]: {
display: 'block',
},
},
search: {
position: 'relative',
borderRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius,
backgroundColor: alpha(theme.palette.common.white, 0.15),
'&:hover': { backgroundColor: alpha(theme.palette.common.white, 0.25) },
marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
marginLeft: 0,
width: '100%',
\[theme.breakpoints.up('sm')\]: { marginLeft: theme.spacing(3), width: 'auto' },
},
searchIcon: {
padding: theme.spacing(0, 2), height: '100%', position: 'absolute', pointerEvents: 'none', display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center',
},
inputRoot: {
color: 'inherit',
},
inputInput: {
padding: theme.spacing(1, 1, 1, 0), paddingLeft: `calc(1em + ${theme.spacing(4)}px)`, transition: theme.transitions.create('width'), width: '100%', \[theme.breakpoints.up('md')\]: { width: '20ch' },
},
toolbar: {
display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between',
},
}));
```

How do i make it work with the most recent version of material ui?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `makeStyles` you define a theme and then wrap your app in a theme provider:

Theme file:

```
export const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#2e7e89',
    },
    secondary: {
      main: '#8eb9ff',
    },
  },
  typography: {
    fontFamily: "'Outfit', sans-serif",
    button: {
      textTransform: 'none',
    },
})
```

App.tsx:

```
 <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
   <App />     
 </ThemeProvider>
```

You can also use the sx prop to customize your styles: https://mui.com/system/getting-started/the-sx-prop/

```
<Button
   sx={{
     display: 'flex',
     marginRight: { xs: '8px', md: '15px', lg: '18px' },
     padding: 0,
     fontSize: '14px',
   }}
> 
  A button
</Button>
```

Comment: What if i want to import the styles in a file, how should i enclose the styles in a component and how should i export and import the styles. And what about the alpha tag in the import? Thanks.

Comment: Try importing alpha from `@mui/core`, as far as importing / exporting styles, you could use css modules as described here: https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/interoperability/